# CSS3 element class below text

Tags: css

My code is very simple, but I'd like to move the css3 triangle to the middle of the text "click". could someone please help me?

```
**HTML**
<li><a href="#" class="arrow">click</a></li>​


**CSS**
li{list-style:none; }
.arrow{
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    display:block;
    border-width: 0 5px 8px 5px;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
}​
```

ONLINE CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/8rRyf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont want to add any extra element, so far this is the only way could figure it out.
Added `text-indent` in li did the trick!

```
li{list-style:none; margin-left:20px; text-indent: -8px;}


.arrow{
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    display:block;
    border-width: 0 5px 8px 5px;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rRyf/24/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to position borders, but something like this should do the trick.

```
li{list-style:none; }

a {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;            
}

.arrow{
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: solid;
    display:block;
    border-width: 0px 5px 8px 5px;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
}


<li><a href="#">click<span class="arrow"> </span></a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rRyf/19/

Comment: thanks for your answer, somehow there is an extra span needs to be added. I figured out by using `text-indent` in li